# How to debug a remote stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures

I want to debug a remote stored procedure with breakpoints like in Visual Studio.

I know it can be achieved through Visual Studio by adding the existing server connection through "step into the procedure" option.

But still using this I can not debug the remote database stored procedure, so how can I achieve this? Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To my knowledge, remote procs cannot be debugged with the debugger.  You can only debug procs locally on the SQL box.  But then my knowledge on this subject is old by 2 or 3 versions.   Maybe in 2012 or 2014 it's become possible?

Comment: check this blog once http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/10/27/unable-to-do-sql-stored-procedure-debugging-remotely-from-vs2010.aspx